# CSS isn't being applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

CSS isn't being applied, can't figure out why. Trying to change the font. This has worked before so don't know why it isn't now. CSS and html files are in the same folder. Working in python/bootstrap/flask/VSC. Here is my css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches');


.container-fluid {
  color: red;
  font-family:'Staatliches', cursive;

}

body {
  font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
}
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Complete Bootstrap 4 Website Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('hello_world')}}"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Crap</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Crud</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cheesey Potato</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Scorpion</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>



</div>
</nav>

<!--- Image Slider -->
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/background.png')}}">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="display-2">HELLO!</h1>
            <h3>WELCOME</h3>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">click here</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">no click here actually</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/background2.png')}}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/background3.png')}}">
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<!--- Jumbotron -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row jumbotron">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
        <p class="lead">This is an example site.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Web Hosting</button></a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>


<!--- Welcome Section -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row welcome text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="display-4">Morning!</h1>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-12">
        <p class="lead">Welcome to my website</p>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>


<!--- Three Column Section -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center padding">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <i class="fas fa-fish fa-5x text-danger"></i>
        <h3>Fish</h3>
        <p>Browse freshwater and exotic fish</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <i class="fas fas fa-dog fa-5x"></i>
        <h3 class="text-danger">Dogs</h3>
        <p>Browse our pedigrees</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <i class="fas fas fa-otter fa-5x"></i>
        <h3>Otters</h3>
        <p>Check out our new range of otters</p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="my-4">
</div>


<!--- Two Column Section -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
        <h2>If you build it...</h2>
        <p>According to Platts estimates and to thermal coal traders who spoke to Platts, 
            Russian producers continue to seek domination on the European market and have been 
            putting in a lot of effort to grab more market shares on the Asian markets such as South 
            Korea and Taiwan.</p>
        <p>Last year, the average free on board (FOB) coal prices for the Atlantic and Pacific markets were 
            both higher compared to 2017, which could be a big incentive for Russia to continue producing and 
            exporting more coal to seaborne destinations, according to Platts.</p>
        <p>Russia’s Energy Minister Alexander Novak briefed on Thursday President Vladimir Putin on the Russian 
            energy sector production in 2018, saying that the coal production of around 433 million tons was 
            planned to be reached in 2020. Russia plans to invest around $22.4 billion 
            (1.5 trillion Russian rubles) in its coal industry and port infrastructure, Novak told Putin.</p>       
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

No changes are being applied when I reload the page in localhost. Any changes made to the HTML are applied, its just the css. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use like this:

  font-family:'Staatliches', cursive !important;

Comment: try to clean the cache. If your using chrome, just open dev tools, and press for a second the reload button, you will se "hard reload". This will clean the front cache. If this didn't work, try to check with dev tools if your css is being loaded and the font. It's possible that another file may be overwriting your file

Comment: tried the !important, still doesn't work. I tried reloading the cache with ctrl+shift+R, which has worked before, but still no luck. Yeah the style.css in devtools is empty but I can't see why. How would I know if another file is overwriting it and why would it do this?

Comment: are you certain that `href="style.css"` is the right path to your CSS file?

Comment: I am certain yes

Answer (score 0):

Just try to request css files for font from header, not by importing them

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

and then check in network panel that the file is being loaded

Comment: @golfumbrella I'm pretty sure, you are making something wrong. Try creating the empty html and css files, and then follow the  instructions from here https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-your-next-web-design-project-e1ad48f1adfa

Comment: @golfumbrella check the Google Chrome's developer tools -> Network to ensure browsers gets the css files loaded

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working in my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tr4c355/pen/WLYGjE):

Are you sure that not having a closing `</body>` and `</html>` tag are not the cause?

Maybe declaring the same relative directory for your style.css file like:

```
<link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Have you checked the style.css file permissions?

Comment: i've closed the body and html tags further down, just didn't include it here. Ive tried the declaring. How do I check file permissions?

Comment: Depending on your host's web server (), you can use the Cpanel file explorer in some cases to set individual file permissions on the server (to 644). or you can go command line if you have cmd access to the web server. Check your css file's name is actually "style.css". I usually declare all my css first and then js libraries, but that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Did you ever get this working or find out what was the issue?

Comment: yeah I needed to put my css file in a folder called static and link to it there like so - <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: for some reason either flask or VScode (can't remember which) can only find it in a folder named static. I think it says this in the flask documentation